# Flatten table into Association Thread where each cell is an association from its column and row header

Tags: list-manipulation, associations

Let's say I have a table in Mathematica like so:
[image: Table]

Where the first row is the header, and first column is also a header (similar to a multiplication table). ie S_A*S_A = Es; S_B*S_A = ss_sigma;

The layout for this list is like so:

```
{
{
{header row},
{"row name1",row item 1, row item 2, etc...}
{"row name 2", row item 1, row item 2, etc...}
}
}
```

How do I flatten this table into an association thread like so:
[image: Desired list]

Comment: Btw.: `S_A`, `ss_sigma` etc. are not valid variable names in Mathematica. Underscores are used to define patterns (look up `Blank` in the documentation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it works with

```
energies = {{{"Column1", "SA", "SB", "SC", "SD", "PxA", "PxB", "PxC", "PxD", "PyA", "PyB", "PyC", "PyD", "PzA", "PzB", "PzC", "PzD"}, {"SA", "Es", "sssigma", 0., "sssigma", 0., "-spsigma", 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., "spsigma", 0., 0., 0., 0.}}}[[1]];
Normal@AssociationThread[
 Flatten@Outer[
   Times,
   energies[[1, 2 ;;]],
   energies[[2 ;;, 1]],
   1
   ],
 Flatten@energies[[2 ;;, 2 ;;]]
 ]
```

> {("SA")^2 -> "Es", "SA" "SB" -> "sssigma", "SA" "SC" -> 0.,   "SA"
>   "SD" -> "sssigma", "PxA" "SA" -> 0., "PxB" "SA" -> "-spsigma",   "PxC"
>   "SA" -> 0., "PxD" "SA" -> 0., "PyA" "SA" -> 0.,   "PyB" "SA" -> 0.,
>   "PyC" "SA" -> 0., "PyD" "SA" -> "spsigma",   "PzA" "SA" -> 0., "PzB"
>   "SA" -> 0., "PzC" "SA" -> 0.,   "PzD" "SA" -> 0.}

Alternatively, you may use `Thread@Rule` instead of `Normal@AssociationThread` (this should be also a bit faster).

Comment: Definitely has to do with association thread, so thanks for that! I'll see if I can find more with that hint.

Comment: Tried that code, so far all I get in return is an empty list: {}. I should mention that my original table is within 2 lists: {   { {row 1},{row2},...,{row 16}  }   }

Comment: Would you be so kind and post copyable code in your question. Then I could have another try.

Comment: {{{"Column1", "SA", "SB", "SC", "SD", "PxA", "PxB", "PxC", "PxD", 
   "PyA", "PyB", "PyC", "PyD", "PzA", "PzB", "PzC", "PzD"}, {"SA", 
   "Es", "sssigma", 0., "sssigma", 0., "-spsigma", 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    "spsigma", 0., 0., 0., 0.}}}

Comment: Ah, and remove `TableForm`. It is just a wrapper for display.

Comment: Thank you! That works!

Comment: You're welcome. When importing data, it is often wrapped in an addition pair of braces (this is used, e.g., for multipage document formats).

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Again my congratulations, this use of Outer and [[a,;;b]] and so ... real good  I will learn , I hopefrom you